# Replace setInterval call with some other algorithm placed inside called function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a [script](http://jsfiddle.net/qEupm/7/), that changes pictures with transparency effect on same place, but I don't like, that it is called with setInterval. Is there some way to have same result, but maybe with some loop from inside function and make a delay there.

Thanks everyone for help.

***UPD:***
Examples of your thoughts are always welcome.

Comment: What don't you like about `setInterval()`? There's nothing wrong with it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

JavaScript doesn't have a `sleep`, and if it did it would block everything until it finished.

There is nothing wrong with `setInterval`.

Comment: The reason for my question is, that I would like to make a plugin out of it, but with setInterval as a part of working script I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Essentially, you just need to stop using the string-to-be-evaled version of the function as that breaks scope (among many other problems) and pass the function you want to call directly.

Comment: I think I understood you, but for safety could you bring some example in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
function changeImage() {
     alert('change picture here');
     setTimeout(changeImage,3000);
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about, and yes, I made the change in the answer!